# React native method is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to call **signInWithFacebook** method inside **AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()** but getting **signInWithFacebook** is undefined. The method works fine if I call it outside the **LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions** function. I cannot seem to able to call any method inside the **LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions**

I'm new to react native please help. Thanks.

```js
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginManager,
  AccessToken,
} = FBSDK;
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { firebaseActions as auth } from "../actions";
const { signInWithFacebook } = auth;



class FacebookLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.onSuccess = this.onSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);
    this.onSignInWithFacebook = this.onSignInWithFacebook.bind(this);
  }

  async onSignInWithFacebook() {

    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
      function (result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          console.log("Login was Cancelled");
        } else {

          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
            (data) => {
              this.props.signInWithFacebook(data.accessToken, this.onSuccess, this.onError);
            }
          );
        }
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log("An error has occured" + error);
      }
    );

  }

  onSuccess({ exists, user }) {
    console.log(
      "Login Success"
    );

  }

  onError(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.onSignInWithFacebook}
        >
          <Text>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { signInWithFacebook })(FacebookLogin);
```

Comment: Are you getting signInWithFacebook() is undefined error or unable to call signInWithFacebook() of undefined error?

Comment: I don't understand why you are sending it to your props. There is no need for it.

Maybe just call signInWithFacebook without this.props in front of it.

Comment: I'm using redux-thunk for api calls, if I don't use props it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay cool. Sorry did not see you are using redux. I think your issue is actually then with the way you are mapping to the props. Try the example below:
`const mapToProps = () => {
 return {
  signInWithFacebook
 }
};

export default connect(mapToProps)(FacebookLogin);`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and let you know.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Can you maybe include your Auth file as well? Because if that did not work then I don't think that it ever has a value. 

Make sure that your function names are exactly the same and that you export it correctly.

Comment: Got it working, see Anoop's answer below. Thank you for taking your time trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this only add one line to your code as:--

```
async onSignInWithFacebook() {
    const _this = this;
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
      function (result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          console.log("Login was Cancelled");
        } else {

          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
            (data) => {
              _this.props.signInWithFacebook(data.accessToken, this.onSuccess, this.onError);
            }
          );
        }
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log("An error has occured" + error);
      }
    );

  }
```

In your code LoginManager emitting a event so your this scope is changed and you got undefined  signInWithFacebook..
notes:--
When attaching a function using addEventListener() the value of this is changed...

Answer (score 1):

Things changed in the last versions.

`logInWithReadPermissions` is a method from **old** react-native-fbsdk version 0.8.0.

`logInWithPermissions` should be used since react-native-fbsdk version 0.10.0.

Comment: I was looking on how to update login to ios fbsdk 5.5 without massive changes(to using the button) and facebooks docs were outdated, thanks a bunch.